# Batch: avoiding specific conflict in FOR loops

Tags: windows, batch

Problem: unexpected behavior (single duplicate) in FOR-loop.

I'm trying to make a simple batch-vbscript interface for mounting and dismounting volumes, among other tasks ("Voltask"). A central part of the function is unique identification of each volume, which i'm trying to achieve by parsing output from MOUNTVOL:

> ```
> \\?\Volume{d35e9775-0176-11d6-a06d-806e6f6e6963}\
>     H:\
> \\?\Volume{d35e9776-0176-11d6-a06d-806e6f6e6963}\
>     F:\
> \\?\Volume{6537febd-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
>     *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***
> \\?\Volume{3fb54500-a257-11e4-8d8d-806e6f6e6963}\
>     *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***
> \\?\Volume{6537febe-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
>     C:\
> \\?\Volume{6537fec3-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
>     A:\
> \\?\Volume{6537fec1-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
>     D:\
> \\?\Volume{6537fec2-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
>     E:\
> ```

The first parse gives some subroutines what they need and makes the data generally more pleasing to handle. Each relevant line from MOUNTVOL is stored into a separate variable number.

```
@ECHO OFF & SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion & SET count=0
REM Basic parse
FOR /F "usebackq" %%5 IN (`
MOUNTVOL ^| FINDSTR /c:\ /c:*
`) DO (
SET /a count+=1
SET !count!=%%5
)
```

The next step is to take this simple output and move a step closer to combining corresponding letters and names: 1 2 3 4 5 -> 11 12 21 22 31...
This way the first number would always represent one volume and the latter the type of data corresponding with the volume, 1=name, 2=letter.

I'm trying to achieve this by parsing the previously gained data with:

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%count%) DO (
SET /a ODD=%%G %%2
IF !ODD! EQU 1 (
SET A=%%G
SET /a A-=!C!
SET /a C+=1
SET B=1
) 
REM Intentionally not using "ELSE"
IF !ODD! EQU 0 (
SET A=%%G
SET /a A-=!C!
SET /a B+=1
)
SET !A!!B!=!%%G!
ECHO !A!!B! Has Data !%%G!
)
```

Just to clear up the arithmetics: the counts result in A increasing every second run and B varying between 1 and 2.

The resulting output as displayed is:

```
11 Has Data \\?\Volume{d35e9775-0176-11d6-a06d-806e6f6e6963}\
12 Has Data H:\
21 Has Data \\?\Volume{d35e9776-0176-11d6-a06d-806e6f6e6963}\
22 Has Data F:\
31 Has Data \\?\Volume{6537febd-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
32 Has Data ***
41 Has Data \\?\Volume{3fb54500-a257-11e4-8d8d-806e6f6e6963}\
42 Has Data ***
51 Has Data \\?\Volume{6537febe-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
52 Has Data C:\
61 Has Data \\?\Volume{d35e9775-0176-11d6-a06d-806e6f6e6963}\
62 Has Data H:\
71 Has Data \\?\Volume{6537fec1-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
72 Has Data D:\
81 Has Data \\?\Volume{6537fec2-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
82 Has Data E:\
```

61 and 62 being duplicates of 11 and 12. As merely a coincidence this would be curious as the values of %G at this exact point are also 11 and 12. This lead me to draw the conclusion that... i just don't see it.

Is !%%G! somehow being misinterpreted or did i make a mistake with the counts? I've banged my head on the screen for so long i'd really appreciate any tips!

EDIT: After a thorough break i realized that after %%G passes 10, conflicts are bound to happen as the !%%G! is interpreted as !11! and !12!, which refer to both first- and second-parse variables. This results in the duplicates. The dilemma, however, remains: how to avoid this?

Setting another layer of localization would solve the problem at the expense of creating others; does not seem to be a viable option.
I could use letters instead of numbers as variables but this would break arithmetics. *Currently researching using shift to replace set /a count+=1 with an equivalent for letters, but so far to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix your code simply by putting a delimiter between the two numbers in your final variable names - I'll use a period:

```
SET !A!.!B!=!%%G!
ECHO !A!.!B! Has Data !%%G!
```

Or you could put a prefix before each name. This is a good idea because you cannot expand a variable name beginning with a digit with normal expansion because it will be confused with a batch argument like `%1`. Not a problem with your code since you use delayed expansion. But variables beginning with a digit is something to generally avoid.

```
SET V!A!!B!=!%%G!
ECHO V!A!!B! Has Data !%%G!
```

I would probably do both. I like the variable beginning with something other than a digit, and visually I like the separation of the two numbers:

```
SET V!A!.!B!=!%%G!
ECHO V!A!.!B! Has Data !%%G!
```

Your code could be dramatically simplified:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0
for /f %%A in ('mountvol ^| findstr /l "\ *"') do (
  set /a "A=count/2+1, B=count%%2+1, count+=1"
  set "V!A!.!B!=%%A"
  echo V!A!.!B!=%%A
)
```

Which should yield:

```
V1.1 Has Data \\?\Volume{d35e9775-0176-11d6-a06d-806e6f6e6963}\
V1.2 Has Data H:\
V2.1 Has Data \\?\Volume{d35e9776-0176-11d6-a06d-806e6f6e6963}\
V2.2 Has Data F:\
V3.1 Has Data \\?\Volume{6537febd-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
V3.2 Has Data ***
V4.1 Has Data \\?\Volume{3fb54500-a257-11e4-8d8d-806e6f6e6963}\
V4.2 Has Data ***
V5.1 Has Data \\?\Volume{6537febe-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
V5.2 Has Data C:\
V6.1 Has Data \\?\Volume{6537fec3-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
V6.2 Has Data A:\
V7.1 Has Data \\?\Volume{6537fec1-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
V7.2 Has Data D:\
V8.1 Has Data \\?\Volume{6537fec2-01bc-11d6-adb5-806e6f6e6963}\
V8.2 Has Data E:\
```

By simplifying the code to using only one loop, with no intermediate variables, there technically is no need for a prefix or delimiter in the variable name. You could simply use the following in my loop:

```
  set "!A!!B!=%%A"
  echo !A!!B! Has Data %%A
```

But I still would keep the prefix and the delimiter.

There may be 10 or more volumes on a machine - mine has 10. As Scott suggests, you can add 100 to the value to get a fixed width variable name that supports up to 99 volumes. I would also use a substring operation to get zero prefixed values, starting with `01`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0
for /f %%A in ('mountvol ^| findstr /l "\ *"') do (
  set /a "A=count/2+101, B=count%%2+1, count+=1"
  set "V!A:~-2!.!B!=%%A"
  echo V!A:~-2!.!B!=%%A
)
```

Comment: All very good points; i'll be experimenting. Especially meaningful later on was pointing out the risks with %1. The first solution rivals my (or rather Scott's) other solution of replacing SET B=1 with SET B=10 in its simplicity. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

Simply de-duplicate (deconflict) the variable names by *prefixing* them
with letters.  For example, on the first pass, use `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, ...,
and/or use `B11`, `B12`, `B21`, `B22`, ..., on the second pass.

In situations like this,
I sometimes find that non-uniform variable name *lengths*
causes some difficulty.  (For example, `A1` ... `A9` are two characters,
but then `A10`, etc., are three characters.) 
I sometimes handle that by starting the numbering at 10 or 11, or 100 or 101. 
For example, if you start with `A10`,
you can have 90 lines of input and only go up to `A99`.

Comment: I'm also trying the method of adding letters, just to learn some more, but the first problem with it is with the arithmetics - set /a should be able to work only with numbers.

Your latter tip was very helpful and indeed constructive in terms of my deductive abilities. Simply replacing SET B=1 with SET B=10 achieved the goal. Thank you!